# How to install pythonext extension in Firefox without creating FF application?

Tags: python, browser

pythonext doc at http://code.google.com/p/pythonext/ says: "The Python extension is downloaded and installed into a Mozilla application as a regular extension"

I don't have a Mozilla application. Just trying to get my .py code to run in FF browser.

Comment: Firefox IS a Mozilla application

Answer (score 3):

> I downloaded pythonext-6.0.0.20110820-WINNT_x86-msvc.xpi for PythonExt 6 Windows with FF 6, but .xpi is not recognized by Windows 7, so not clear how to install it.

Go to the addon mananger and click on the gear button.
Then click Install addon from file.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Ehm... it's the first sentence under title: "This project provides Python Mozilla bindings (PyXPCOM) that enables Python to be used inside of Mozilla applications like Firefox, Thunderbird and XULRunner."

If you haven't yet noticed, Mozilla is "company" and their "products" are Firefox, Thunderbird, etc. So you can simply install that Pythonext and your scripts will work in Firefox, that's all to it..

Comment: I downloaded pythonext-6.0.0.20110820-WINNT_x86-msvc.xpi for PythonExt 6 Windows with FF 6, but .xpi is not recognized by Windows 7, so not clear how to install it.